# Custom Checkbox Not Working in Chrome on Windows

Tags: css, google-chrome, checkbox

I have a custom checkbox built with only CSS and images -- no Javascript. It's been working for months on many browsers: Chrome, Firefox, IE on Windows and Safari, Chrome, Firefox on Mac.

Recently, Chrome on Windows stopped working. When you click the checkbox, nothing happens.

I believe the problematic Chrome version is: 39.0.2171.65 m

Plnkr here that demonstrates the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/zUhrCJcLzeFxjkfFJfio?p=preview

Any ideas or workarounds?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input id="cb1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cb1">I am a checkbox.</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old),
input[type=radio]:not(old) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label,
input[type=radio]:not(old) + label {
  color: #8a8a8a;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding-left: 28px;
  background-image: url("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-nUA70hCTkQg/VHJw1D_AMQI/AAAAAAAAAtM/H2hV7zay0ZY/w34-h36-no/radio-unchecked.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 18px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label,
input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label {
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Ej9nmrhevVg/VHJw1AxHuAI/AAAAAAAAAtI/UfonPHsJBMc/w34-h36-no/radio-checked.png");
}
```

Comment: what is :not(old) ???

Comment: :not is the css pseudo-class for negation. I'm using it to hide styles from older browsers that don't completely support CSS3 selectors. Explanation here: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/hiding-rules-with-the-negation-pseudo-class/

Comment: I know that but confused of using old. That should be odd right??

Comment: Explanation of how I used it here: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/hiding-rules-with-the-negation-pseudo-class/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in Chrome v39. See here for details:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=435923

You can wait for the next Chrome release, or use @RaianaLadeira's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the exact same problem. Solved by inverteing the order of the pseudo classes in css

Where it was:

```
input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label
```

it has to become

```
input[type=radio]:checked:not(old) + label
```

Comment: Thanks @RaianaLadeira. It's strange that it was working fine and only stopped working in Chrome v39.  Also strange that it still works in other browsers.